# Rust client for Twilio's API example program error

Tags: rust, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to get this exercise to run but keep getting a (permissions?) error on my AccountSid, which should be correct.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Something went wrong, ResponseError(ResponseContent { status: 401, content: "{\"code\": 20003, \"detail\": \"Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.\", \"message\": \"Authentication Error - invalid username\", \"more_info\": \"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003\", \"status\": 401}", entity: Some(UnknownValue(Object({"code": Number(20003), "detail": String("Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect."), "message": String("Authentication Error - invalid username"), "more_info": String("https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003"), "status": Number(401)}))) })'
```

Initially, I got a "this function takes 21 arguments but 18 arguments were supplied" error but fixed it by supplying the correct amount of None arguments to `twilio_api::create_message`

After that I get this AccoutSid error.

Here is the walk-through: https://www.twilio.com/docs/openapi/generating-a-rust-client-for-twilios-api

And here is my code for the exercise. I have the .env filled out correctly.

```rust
use dotenv;
use openapi::apis::{configuration::Configuration, default_api as twilio_api};
use std::env;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
  // Securely import sensitive credentials and values from `.env` instead of inlining their values.
  dotenv::dotenv().expect("Failed to read .env file");
  let account_sid = env::var("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID").expect("Failed to parse Account SID");
  let api_key = env::var("TWILIO_API_KEY").expect("Failed to parse API Key");
  let api_key_secret = env::var("TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET").expect("Failed to parse API Key Secret");
  let from = env::var("TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER").expect("Failed to parse 'from' number");
  let to = env::var("TO_NUMBER").expect("Failed to parse 'to' number");

  // Create a new, default client configuration.
  let mut twilio_config = Configuration::default();
  // Apply your Basic Auth credentials to the client configuration.
  twilio_config.basic_auth = Some((api_key, Some(api_key_secret)));

  // Asynchronously send the message "Ahoy, Rustacean! " to the `to` number from your Twilio phone number.
  let message = twilio_api::create_message(
    &twilio_config,
    &account_sid,
    &to,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    Some("Ahoy, Rustacean! "),
    None,
    None,
    Some(&from),
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
    None,
  )
  .await;

  let result = match message {
    Ok(result) => result,
    Err(error) => panic!("Something went wrong, {:?}", error),
  };

  // Once successful, print out the SID of the sent message.
  println!("{:?}", result.sid);
}
```

Comment: HTTP error code 401 means "Unauthorized". This means your API key and/or API key secret are not valid. I'm voting to close the question as unreproducible since the error you've pasted has to do with configuration data and not the code itself.

Comment: Hello

I have the same issue running twilio given rust example, using a standard API key created in `Auth tokens & API keys` (bound to Ireland), my Twilio account SID found in `account` > `General settings`.

Would you by chance have found what was the issue with your credentials ?

Comment: @Laurent Erignoux Never did solve this. I had to move on after spending a fair bit of time with no luck. If I do figure it out I'll definitely come back and update the post. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to fix mine. The Api Keys are region based and the demo uses US (the default). It worked for me after using a USA Api Key instead of an Ireland one.

In case it can solve yours or other people

Comment: Going to give this one more try so thanks for the follow up reply and will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just got through the same error:

- Install cargo-edit like the doc recommends, and use cargo add to download the crates. This resolved my error.
- After that I had another issue with the parameters given in the example code, so I changed it like this:

```
  let body = "SMS test was successful!".to_string();

  let message = twilio_api::create_message(
    &twilio_config, // 1
    &account_sid,   // 2
    &to,            // 3
    None,           // 4
    None,  // 5
    None,           // 6
    None, // 7
    None,           // 8
    None,           // 9
    None,               // 10
    None,           // 11
    None,           // 12
    None,           // 13
    None,           // 14
    None,           // 15
    None,           // 16
    None,           // 17
    Some(&from),           // 18
    None,           // 19
    Some(&body),           // 20
    None,           // 21
  )
  .await;
```